# Graph Theory: Calculating Clustering Coefficient

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, graph-theory

I'm doing some research and I've come to a point where I have calculate the clustering coefficient of a graph.

According to [this paper directly related to my research](http://tam.cornell.edu/tam/cms/manage/upload/SS_nature_smallworld.pdf):

> The clustering coefﬁcient C(p) is
>   deﬁned as follows. Suppose that a
>   vertex v has k<sub>v</sub> neighbours; then at
>   most (k<sub>v</sub> * (k<sub>v</sub>-1)) / 2 edges can
>   exist between them (this occurs when
>   every neighbour of v is connected to
>   every other neighbour of v). Let C<sub>v</sub>
>   denote the fraction of these allowable
>   edges that actually exist. Deﬁne C as
>   the average of C<sub>v</sub> over all v

But [this wikipedia article on the subject says differently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient):

> C = (number of closed triplets) / (number of connected triples)

It seems to me that the latter is more computationally expensive.

So really my question is: are they equivalent?

It should be noted that the paper is cited by the Wikipedia article.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: There's a site for that http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah, I did not know about that. I shall ask the same over there. Thanks

Comment: @Henk - sure? Isn't cstheory for *research* level CS? I'm not sure they're receptive to this kind of question.

Comment: May belong on http://math.stackexchange.com/ though

Comment: @Steve: I don't really know. But the current top question on their homepages is "What hierarchies and/or hierarchies theorems do you know?" so I think there's some spread in quality there too.

Comment: Wait, how do you get 1/K for the first method for the complete graph? Looks like it should be 1 to me.

Comment: @Whatang you are correct, excuse the mistake, it's been a long day. I have edited my question appropriately. I still don't know if they are equivalent though.

@Steve314 Could you clarify your reasoning please, I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @Griffin - neither am I, to be honest ;-) Comment deleted since I'll assume Whatang knows better than me what he's talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think they're equivalent. The wiki page you link to gives a proof that the triples formulation is equivalent to the fraction of possible edges formulation when calculating the *local* clustering coefficient, i.e. calculated just at a vertex. From there it seems that you just need to show that

```
sum_v lambda(v)/tau(v) = 3 x # triangles / # connected triples
```

where `lambda(v)` is the number of triangles containing v, and `tau(v)` is the number of connected triples for which v is the middle vertex, i.e. adjacent to each of the other 2 edges.

Now each triangle gets counted three times in the numerator of the LHS. However, each connected triple is only counted once for the middle vertex on the LHS, so the denominators are the same.

Comment: I'll have to come back fresh tomorrow to go over what you said again. 

Looking further down the page however, it seems that it is "Network average clustering coefficient" I am looking for.

Since the page proves that the two methods are equivalent for local clustering coefficint. And that Network average clustering coefficient is just the average of all the local cluster coefficients. It would seem that the two methods are equivalent since the method in the paper and the citation in that section are from the same authors (Watts and Strogatz).

What do you say?

Comment: Yeah, the network average is what you're looking at. You just need to prove that the sum for the network average using the fraction of edges formulation is equivalent to the global clustering coefficient presented at the top of the page - this is what my answer is doing.

Comment: Well, if you feel you want to accept it, yes :P But feel free to work it through and convince yourself that I'm right first!

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help. I will report back tomorrow.

Answer (score 12):

The two formulas are not the same; they are two different ways in which the global clustering coefficient can be calculated.

One way is by averaging the clustering coefficients (C_i [1]) of all nodes (this is the method you quoted from Watts and Strogatz). However, in [2, p204] Newman argues that this method is less preferable than the second one (the one you got from wikipedia). He justifies by pointing how the value of the global clustering coeff can be dominated by nodes of low degree, due to C_i's denominator [1]. So, in a network with many nodes of low degrees, you end up with a large value for the global clustering coeff, which Newman argues would be unrepresentative.

However, many network studies (or, in my experience, at least many studies concerned with online social networks) seem to have used this method, so in order to be able to compare your results with theirs, you would require to use the same method. Furthermore, the critique raised by Newman does not affect the extent to which comparisons of global clustering coefficients can be made, provided the same method was used in measuring them.

The two formulae are different and were proposed at different moments in time. The one you quoted from Watt and Strogatz is older, which is perhaps why it seems to have been more commonly used. Newman also explains that the two formulae are **far** from equivalent, and shouldn't be used as such. He says they can give substantially different numbers for a given network, however doesn't explain why.

[1] C_i = (number of pairs of neighbours of *i* that are connected) / (number of pairs of neighbours of *i*)

[2] Newman, M.E.J.. Networks : an introduction. Oxford New York: Oxford University Press, 2010. Print.

Edit:

I am including here a series of calculations for the same ER random graph. You can see how the two methods give different results, even for undirected graphs. (done using Mathematica)

[image]

Comment: And this is backed up by this paper: http://i11www.iti.uni-karlsruhe.de/_media/projects/spp1126/files/sw-acct-05.pdf (see sections I & II-A)

Answer (score 2):

I partially disagree with Whatang. These methods are only equivalent for undirected graphs. However for directed graphs they return different results. In my opinion the local clustering coefficient method is the correct one. Not to mention its less computationally expensive. For example

```
  <-----
4 -----> 5
|<--||-->
|   ||
|-> 6  -> 7

4(IN [5,6], OUT [5,6])
5(IN [4,6], OUT [4])
6(IN [4], OUT [4,5,7])
7(IN [6], OUT [])
```

central = 6

localCC = 2 / 4*3 = 1/6

globalCC = 1 / 3

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't trust that wikipedia article. The first formula you cited is currently defined as the Mean Clustering Coefficient, hence it is the mean of all local clustering coefficients for a graph *g*. This is in no way the same as the global clustering coefficient, as xk_id aptly put it.

Answer (score 0):

there is a great page to learn the basics from!

http://www.learner.org/courses/mathilluminated/interactives/network/

all about cluster coefficients, small world and so on ...